# resourceDayGrid with vertical days headers

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm using resourceDayGrid for recreation functionality of grid previously used:
[previous grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTHzR.png).
In resourceDayGrid - day headers are displayed under resources (as columns):
[current resourceDayGrid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhbCK.png)

Is there any property/configuration changing day header display position to vertical (rows)?

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't.

The closest you could get to your original grid is the [timeline](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timeline-view) view which splits the dates/times and the resources onto separate axes, but it's always arranged so that resources are on the Y axis and times/dates on the X axis - i.e. the reverse of your previous arrangement. But the effect is similar.

There is a demo [here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timeline-standard-view-demo) showing the day/week/month versions of the timeline so you can get a idea how it looks. There are some things you can configure, but flipping the axes isn't one of them unfortunately.

You could check if anyone has requested this feature in fullCalendar, and vote for it, or request it yourself - see [here](https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features) for details.